# increase the # of points in a DFT, increase the processing

Tags: fourier

I have a question which is closely related to this one:
[FFT Processing Gain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16330/fft-processing-gain)

^that discussion is a bit general so I want to ask a very objective question to see if I can apply that knowledge:

If I collect one million time samples and perform a one million point DFT, roughly what DFT processing gain (in dB) improvement can I expect to achieve in pulling a weak spectral component up above background noise in comparison to a 100 point DFT?

I guess that answer is 100,000. isn't it?

we have 9999910 more bins.

Comment: For a single sinusoid, the link in the FFT processing gain discussion suggests a gain of: $10log_{10}(M/2)$.

Comment: So, to be explicit, in the example i was considering would it be: 10log10(1,000,000/2)

M is the number of DFT bins right? I always see M written as the frequency bin number being considered. 

So I just do that 10log10(m/2) calculation for both sizes and then compare them?

is that correct?

Comment: Yes, M is the total number of bins. You are right, do the calculation for both sides and compare them. What I think is that gain is valid only for a single tone. You might prove me wrong.

Comment: Please forgive me but I don't quite understand, what does that mean, 'gain is valid only for a single tone' ?

Comment: you mean for a single frequency component and not for the number of DFT points being considered as a whole?

Comment: Gain is valid if in time domain I've only a single tone. More DFT points I collect, more gain I've. But for a wide-band signal, or for example, OFDM, this might not hold.